# how to upgrade angular dependency using typings (typescript nwebie)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

i'm using following grate [seed project](https://github.com/brechtbilliet/angular-typescript-webpack).

my problem is that it uses angular 1.5.0 and I want to upgrade it to 1.6.0

I know how to upgrade deps inside package.json file, 
the problem is with typings -

I can see following definitions in the project (typings.json)

```
{
 "globalDependencies": {
     "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160517064839",
```

so the problem is - where this **20160517064839** numbers taken from?
i guess there must be some command like:

**typings install angular@1.6.0**

but i didnt manage to find it in any place...

Thanks forwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number refers to a particular commit on GitHub.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/brechtbilliet/angular-typescript-webpack/blob/master/package.json#L15-L23), the example uses the new `@types` npm modules instead of typings. This means that you don't need typings at all. Just make sure you have installed the npm modules with:

> $ npm install

And also ensure that you are using typescript >= 2.0.

> $ tsc -v

You need to install angular first and then the typings.